# Engine vibrations in neutral gear and RPM needle jumping (stopped after a few months)

Tags: vibration, rpm

A few months ago, I felt vibrations, lasting a few seconds, in my Mazda 6 whenever I had been driving for a bit, and then stopped (e.g. at a red light) in neutral. Also, letting the car roll in neutral gear would make the RPM needle fluctuate up and down.

I haven't had any other problems, and have not had the car serviced, but the weird thing is that after a few months (maybe as the weather got warmer?) these problems stopped and today there were no vibrations and no jumping of the RPM needle.

What could be the cause of this, and why has it now stopped? Should I get it fixed?

Comment: Nothing worse to diagnose than an issue which goes away. A mechanic would turn you around with an hour's labor charge and discover nothing is the matter.